# Is there a way to remove speaker's noise from microphone input on Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, microphone, speakers

I need to record what I say with my microphone whilst sometimes having something coming from my loudspeakers.

Is it somehow possible on Linux to seperate my voice from what's being recorded from the speakers?

I imagine it like this:

Having a software that records what's being outputted to the speakers and what comes into the mic, and then removes everything that looks very similiar to the speaker data in the mic-data, so that I only have my own noises and speech left.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is "echo cancelling".

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you might want to "[Enable Echo / Noise Cancellation Of Microphone Input On Your Linux Desktop](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/09/how-to-enable-echo-noise-cancellation.html)":
Edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
With this at the end:

```
.ifexists module-echo-cancel.so
load-module module-echo-cancel aec_method=webrtc source_name=echocancel sink_name=echocancel1
set-default-source echocancel
set-default-sink echocancel1
.endif
```

Then run: `pulseaudio -k` and select the new device in sound settings.

Answer (score -1):

This is really not physically possible.

Noise-cancelling headphones work by having a very tight tolerance between the extra little mics inside the headphones & the speakers in there. That means they can quite rapidly phase-cancel what they're hearing.

Phones & tablets achieve a similar thing by using multiple mics, again with known characteristics & measurements.

Once your mic & speakers are not closely-meshed together like that, physics is just not on your side.

If your sound source is mono, then you can reduce the apparent loudness to a mono mic placed dead centre between them by reversing the phase of one side. [Idk any software product that would do that, but it's not beyond the realms of possibility there's one out there].

Failing that, you'll just have to do what everyone else does… wear a headset.